# How to punctuate when using an introduction phrase

Tags: phrases, punctuation

I’d like to know which kind of punctuation is needed if you want to express the following:

*You see I no longer fear death.*

Do I treat this as two sentences, ending both with a period (full stop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a common mistake made by newcomers to ELU – you haven't provided enough context.

I think valid arguments could be made for any of these options:

> *You see? I no longer fear death.
>
>   You see, I no longer fear death.
>
>   You see: I no longer fear death.
>
>   You see; I no longer fear death.
>
>   You see! I no longer fear death!*

Personally, I like any of those over the one you've proposed:

> *You see. I no longer fear death*.

but my final choice would depend on what comes beforehand, and how I wanted to portray the narrator who fears death no more.

Comment: Would it be totally incorrect to have no punctuation besides the period at the end? It feels like the sentence becomes some kind of declarative statement with only a period.